# How can I move an object from one object's array to another object's array with the fewest dependencies?

Tags: ruby, arrays, oop, dependencies

I have two objects with container arrays (Station and Carriage) and I want to move a third object (Passenger) from a station to a carriage.

I'm using the following method within my Carriage class (passengers is just an empty array), but whilst this does board the passengers on the carriage, they still remain in the station meaning I'm just cloning them rather than moving them.

```
def board(passenger)
  passengers << passenger
end
```

I could fix this by passing another argument to the board method (station) and then delete the passenger from the station's own array all from this one method as below but this seems like bad practice.

```
def board(passenger, station)
  passengers << passenger
  station.passengers.delete(passenger)
end
```

I've been reading about Object Oriented Design and am aware that I should minimise any dependencies between classes... and this code above seems to flout a lot of the guidelines of good OOD because:

1. My Carriage class is reaching into the Station class
2. My board method depends upon two arguments being passed in the
   correct order

Is there a better way for me to achieve this with fewer class dependencies?

Comment: `station.passengers.delete(passenger)` violates the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). You just need to create another method in the `Station` class, for example `get_passenger(passenger)`, and you're good to go, the dependencies here are natural, in my opinion. it's like `Carriage` is asking the `Station` to send a specific Passenger, which is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think in term of messages, things will get easier to figure out.At first the passengers belongs to `Station`. So when the `Carriage` wants a passenger to get onto it, it has to send the message to the `Station` asking it to send a passenger in. So I think a better way to implement this is:

```
class Station
  # First version
  # get any passenger
  def get_passenger
     # this will return the first one and remove it from the array
     passengers.shift       
  end 

  # Second version
  # Get a specific passenger
  # in this case the board method of Carriage 
  # will normally depend on the passenger as 
  # well as the station
  def get_passenger(passenger)
     if(passengers.include?(passenger))
       passengers.delete(passenger)
     else
       raise "Passenger not found!"
     end
  end
end
```

in the `Carriage` class's `board` method you will only need to dependency inject the `station` from where passengers will board.

```
class Carriage
  # board any passenger from the station
  def board(station)
    passengers << station.get_passenger
  end
  # Board a specific passenger from the station
  def board(passenger, station)
    passengers << station.get_passenger(passenger)
  end
end
```

and if you want to be free from injecting the arguments in this order, and you're using Ruby >= 2.1, you can use [Ruby keyword arguments](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) instead.

Another approach I think of is to make the messages flow between passenger and station, and passenger and carriage.

```
class Passenger
  # the passenger can be in one station or
  # one carriage at the same time
  attr_accessor :station, :carriage

  def board(carriage)
    carriage.board(self)
    station.remove_passenger(self)
  end
end

class Station
  attr_accessor :passengers
  def remove_passenger(passenger)
    passengers.delete(passenger)
  end
end

class Carriage
  attr_accessor :passengers
  def board(passenger)
    passengers << passenger
  end
end
```

Now you just make a passenger board, by just providing to which carriage to board.

```
passenger.board(carriage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right not to want to add a second parameter to your method - you don't need to.

Instead, create a Passenger instance method that will take care of this for you:

```
passenger.remove_from_station
```

And the code could be:

```
def remove_from_station
  Station.delete(self)
end
```

This way you don't have to add a bunch of redundant, fragile parameters to your method call.

Then when the passenger boards:

```
def board(passenger)
  passengers << passenger
  passenger.remove_from_station
end
```

Comment: Maybe this needs to be `Station#remove_passenger` instead?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Take a look at [Nafaa's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418538/179125). It may very well be a better solution in many cases.

To rephrase your question: Who should manage the relationship between a Passenger and a Carriage, and between a Passenger and a Station?

I think you've identified correctly that it makes sense neither for a Carriage to manage a Passenger's relationship with a Station, nor for a Station to manage a Passenger's relationship with a Carriage.

The simplest solution, it seems, would be to let the Passenger manage its own relationships with both the Carriage and the Station. For example:

```
class Passenger
  attr_reader :station, :carriage

  def enter_carriage(new_carriage)
    leave_station!
    @carriage = new_carriage
    self.carriage.add_passenger(self)
  end

  def leave_carriage!
    self.carriage.remove_passenger(self)
    @carriage = nil
  end

  def enter_station(new_station)
    leave_carriage!
    @station = new_station
    self.station.add_passenger(self)
  end

  def leave_station!
    self.station.remove_passenger(self)
    @station = nil
  end
end
```

This way Carriage and Station just need to provide `add_passenger` and `remove_passenger`, and their internal implementations can be changed freely.

P.S. It looks like you're doing a great job of building up your OOP foundations. If you're in the market for a great Ruby-centric OOP book, I *highly* recommend Sandi Metz' [*Practical Object-Oriented Design In Ruby*](http://www.poodr.com/).

Comment: This way you're making the `Passenger` depends on two other objects  a `station` and a `carriage`, so the problem of too many dependencies is not solved. And you're just writing too much of additional code. If you imagine that the messages are flowing between station and carriage, this will be much simpler.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer That was my first thought as well. It's a compelling argument, to be sure.

Comment: I added another approach to my answer, which take advantage of yours.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here, but there are arguments for and against all of these approaches.

The key to solving the problem is to identify the correct responsibilities of the three objects.

Both the carriage and the station are responsible for containing passengers and providing interfaces for passengers to be added and removed.  Neither is responsible for maintaining the state of the object that currently contains the passenger.  (i.e. the station is not responsible for removing the passenger from the carriage when they alight.)

The passenger should take responsibility for maintaining their current location - but this should not be tightly coupled to the location itself.

So, instead of having `enter station`, `enter_carriage` etc, there could simply be an `enter` method which receives an object that provides an interface for entering and leaving (e.g. a carriage or station).  The passenger then simply leaves the current container and enters the new one.

p.s.  Don't use bang methods (e.g. `leave_station!`) unless you wish to alert other developers that there is a specific danger in using this method over some other provided alternative.  The bang in this case is misleading as the method is a normal mutator.